# How do I Show/Hide partial view based on result I get from service call using jQuery AJAX in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to have a page where I can enter loan number then I will call a WCF get service to see if a loan number is valid. If loan# is valid, I want to show loan related data (partial view) on the same page.

Here is my main View:

```
@model LoanStatus.Web.Models.Validate    
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Validate";
}    
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") 
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
}    

<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(function ($) {
        $("#txtssn").mask("9999");
    });

    function validateRequest() {

        var $form = $('form');
        if ($form.valid()) {
            $.support.cors = true;

            var lnkey = $('#txtlnkey').val();                

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:54662/Service1/ValidateRequest/" + encodeURIComponent(lnkey),                    
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",  //jsonp?
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#Result').html('Loading....');

                    if (response.ValidateRequestResult.toString().toUpperCase() == 'TRUE') {
                        alert('validated');

                    } else {
                        alert('cannot validated' + response.ValidateRequestResult.toString().toUpperCase());
                        //$("#Result").hide();
                    }

                    $('#Result').html(response.ValidateRequestResult);
                    //alert(response.ValidateRequestResult.toString());
                },
                error: function (errormsg) {
                    alert("ERROR! \n" + JSON.stringify(errormsg));                        
                }
            });
            //
        } else {
            $('#Result').html('Input Validation failed');
        }
    }
</script>   

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Log in Form</legend>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LoanKey, new{}) 
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LoanKey, new { @id = "txtlnkey" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LoanKey)
                </li>                    
            </ol>
            <input type="button" value="Get Status" onclick="javascript:validateRequest();" />
        </fieldset>
    }

<div id="Result">    
    @if (ViewBag.Validated)
    {
        @Html.Action("GetLoanInfo");
    }
</div>
```

Below is my controller:

```
namespace LoanStatus.Web.Controllers
{
    public class ValidateController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Validate/
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new Validate() {LoanKey = "", Last4Ssn = ""};    
            ViewBag.Validated = false;                
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Validate model, bool validated)
        {
            // do login stuff
            ViewBag.Loankey = model.LoanKey;
            ViewBag.Validated = true;    
            return View(model);
        }


        public ActionResult GetLoanInfo() // SHOWs Search REsult
        {
           return PartialView("_LoanInfoPartial", ViewBag.Loankey);
        }

    }
}
```

I want to have '`@Html.Action("GetLoanInfo");`' rendered only if jQuery AJAX service call returns TRUE (Where I have `alert('validated')`. I am not sure how to do that. My issue can be resolved if I can set value to `ViewBag.Validated` in  `success:function()`. But based on what I read, it cannot be set in jQuery.

I tried `$("#Result").hide();` and `$("#Result").show();` but it did not work. Please help.

Comment: It is possible that `.hide()` and `.show()` are not working if `@if (ViewBag.Validated)` is false... firstly, that is server-side code.. what you need to do is render it, but then immediately call `.hide()` in `$(document).onready(`

Comment: Also, in your example above, I see you have `.hide()` commented out, but there's no `.show()` commented anywhere. Did you forget to use it or you just removed it completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try with this:

In your function validateRequest() ajax success, at the place where you are showing alert('validated'); use this and try:

```
$('#Result').load('@Url.Action("GetLoanInfo", "Validate")');
```

In your view make Result div empty

```
<div id="Result"> </div>
```

Tell me if it helps.